# Disable predictive text on iPhone for a form field

Tags: iphone, html, forms

Is there an attribute which I can specify for an `<input>` element which would turn off the predictive text functionality for this given field?

Something along the lines

```
<input type="text" predictive="disabled" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the user side you can

> Settings > General > Keyboard >
>   Auto-Correction On/Off.

from the app side, i don't think it can be done.

Answer (score 11):

There are some options:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
```

Comment: I've done these and iOS is ignoring them.

Answer (score 6):

On a per form field basis you can always do the following:

```
<input type="text" autocorrect="off" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As of September 28, 2023 disabling these two parameters is hiding the predictive text bar in iOS: autocorrect and spellcheck.

https://codesandbox.io/s/disable-predictive-text-ttncd4