# Disable Predictive Text on iPad form field

Tags: php, html, ios, ipad

Has any person successfully managed to disable predictive text on an iPad within a form field.

I don't want users to have to switch this off in their iPad settings in order to use the website, but it is very important to somehow disable the predictive text

I have tried autocomplete="off" but with no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722623/disable-predictive-text-on-iphone-for-a-form-field

Comment: Predictive text is a feature of the iOS and can only be managed if you create an App